# Terraform use new created ressource from for_each

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I try to create groups and projects in gitlab with terraform. Later I want to create a new resource "project_membership" to give the new projects the groups as members. Therefore I need the Group_ID and the Project ID.
If I create all resources in own resource blocks, I can refer to it with `${gitlab_group.NAME_OF_THE_RESSOURCE.id}` but when I use for_each I do not specify a name. How I can get the group and project IDs?

```
terraform {
  backend "http" {
  }
  required_providers {
    gitlab = {
      source = "gitlabhq/gitlab"
      version = "~> 3.1"
    }
  }
}

locals {
  services_project_names = toset( [
      "values", 
      "releases", 
      "design", 
      "execution"
    ] )
  permission_project_names = toset( [ 
      "vendor", 
      "maintainer"
    ] )
}

################################
#### permissions repository ####
################################

resource "gitlab_group" "permissions_group" {
  name        = var.service_name
  path        = var.service_name
  parent_id   = var.permissions_parent_grp
  visibility_level       = "private"
}

resource "gitlab_group" "permissions_sub_group" {
  for_each = local.permission_project_names
  name        = "${var.service_name}_${each.key}"
  path        = "${var.service_name}_${each.key}"
  parent_id   = "${gitlab_group.permissions_group.id}"
  visibility_level       = "private"
}

############################
#### service repository ####
############################

resource "gitlab_group" "services_group" {
  name        = var.service_name
  path        = var.service_name
  parent_id   = var.services_parent_grp
  visibility_level       = "private"
}

resource "gitlab_project" "services_projects" {
  for_each = local.services_project_names
  name                   = "${var.service_name}_${each.key}"
  default_branch         = "main"
  description            = ""
  issues_enabled         = false
  merge_requests_enabled = false
  namespace_id           = "${gitlab_group.services_group.id}"
  snippets_enabled       = false
  visibility_level       = "private"
  wiki_enabled           = false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference individual values created via `for_each` by using the key that was used in the `for_each`. In your case here are some examplels:

```
"${gitlab_project.services_projects["values"]}"

"${gitlab_project.services_projects["releases"]}"
```

To get the ID of a specific project:

```
gitlab_project.services_projects["values"].id
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. If I create the name of the project on the fly, can you tell me how to use this in your soloution? (name is "${var.service_name}_${each.key}")

Comment: The `name` attribute is not related to my answer at all. You aren't using the name value to lookup the project, you are using the `for_each` key value. It's the string in your `services_project_names` variable. You would access the dynamic name later, via this:

`gitlab_project.services_projects["values"].name`